# Как заменить часть HTML на основе выборки его содержимого

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, replace

Друзья есть текст в виде `html`

```
$string = "
    <p> some text</p>
    <h3>h3 text1</h3>
    <p> some text</p>
    some text
    <h3>h3 text2</h3>
    <h3>h3 text3</h3>
    ........
";
```

где надо заменить `h3` на `a href` следующим образом

Как то найти значение `h3` (h3 text1 | h3 text2 | h3 text3)

передать функции `getSlug('h3 text1')`, которая у меня готова, которая возвращает новое значение после некоторой обработки,и это новое значение уже вставляем в `a href="#новое значение"`

```
    $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '|<h3>(.[^<]*)<\/h3>\w|',
        function ($matches)
        {
            $h3 = $matches[0];//подразумеваю что получил h3 целиком
            $last_h3_Position = strpos($h3, '</h3>');//Находим позицию закрывающего h3 (</h3>)
            $h3_text = substr($h3, 4 ,$last_h3_Position);//Получить текст между открывающего и закрывающего тегами

               //return getSlug($matches[0]);
               return '<a href="#'.getSlug($h3_text).'">'.$h3_text.'</a>';
        },
        $string
    );
    echo $string;
```

Результат надеялся получить такой:

```
$string = "
    <p> some text</p>
    <a href='#slug1'>h3 text1</a>
    <p> some text</p>
    some text
    <a href='#slug2'>h3 text2</a>
    <a href='#slug3'>h3 text3</a>
    ........
";
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: А если упростить регулярку до `|<h3>(.*?)</h3>|` да и текст между тегами у вас уже заключен в круглые скобки, а следовательно доступен в $matches[1]

Comment: http://ideone.com/qOGcDu

Comment: @Mike Так я что все правильно сделал кроме регулярки ? с $matches[1] согласен ,как то проморгал

Comment: Ну да, регулряка чуть кривая, основная проблема в `\w` которая требовала некую букву после </h3>. излишняя `\\` вряд ли играла роль. Ну и какое то кривое выделение строки между тегами, которое как раз заменяется matches[1]

Comment: @Mike Спасибо огромное,добавь как ответ чтоб я и другие заценили :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы практически все верно сделали. Только регулярка требует букву (`\w`) после `</h3>` и может быть еще немного упрощена. А так же внутри callback функции, все, что было выделено в первые круглые скобки, доступно в `$matches[1]` (в `$matches[0]` все совпадение целиком).

```
$string = "
    <p> some text</p>
    <h3>h3 text1</h3>
    <p> some text</p>
    some text
    <h3>h3 text2</h3>
    <h3>h3 text3</h3>
    ........
";
 $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '|<h3>(.*?)</h3>|',
        function ($matches)
        {
               return '<a href="#'.getSlug($matches[1]).'">'.$matches[1].'</a>';
        },
        $string
    );
    echo $string;
```